# Angular cache Google Map direction service

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, service, factory, direction

I have this method in my factory

```
function getGoogleMapPath(src) {
        var promises = [];

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        src.forEach(function(path) {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            directionsService.route(path, function(response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    defer.resolve(response); // i want to cache this response

                    return;
                } 
                console.log(status);
                defer.reject(status);
            });                

            promises.push(defer.promise);
        });

        return $q.all(promises);
    }
```

and I have 2 views in different states accessing it using promises, but I run into `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`

to fix this problem, i want to cached the direction when i get them instead of asking for the direction twice.

How can I cached it in my factory?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**A new service that will act as the cache:**

```
// declare a new service to act as the cache
angular.app('myApp').service('myCache', function() {

  // initialize an object to be the cache dictionary
  this.directions = {};

});
```

**Use the above cache service within your existing factory:**

```
// inject the new cache service into your existing factory
angular.app('myApp').factory('googleMaps', function(myCache) {

  function getGoogleMapPath(src) {
    var promises = [];

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    src.forEach(function(path) {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      // check if this path is in cache
      if (myCache[path]) {

        //  and use it, if it is present in the cache
        defer.resolve(myCache[path]);

      } else {  // new path - call Google Maps service

        directionsService.route(path, function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            // this is where new directions are added into the cache
            myCache.directions[path] = response;

            defer.resolve(response); // i want to cache this response

            return;
          }
          console.log(status);
          defer.reject(status);
        });

      }

      promises.push(defer.promise);
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
  }

  return {
    getGoogleMapPath: getGoogleMapPath
  };
});
```

I haven't tested this - so there could be some more issues that you need to iron out. But this should give you an approach to implement caching the responses.